# jquery loop match and position

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im kinda new to jquery/javascript and I have a task that I need help with. I am making a seating chart. Each desk object has a data-id. The user objects also have data-id's. What I would ideally like to do is on page load, jquery/javascript would loop through all the desk objects and all the user objects and find matches. If there is a match, re-position the user object over the desk object to represent a user sitting at that desk. I have no idea where to start, any help would be appreciated....

A basic example of what it looks like right now

```
<td class="desk" data-id="4-1"></td>//desk object
<td class="desk" data-id="4-2"></td>//desk object
<td class="desk" data-id="4-3"></td>//desk object

<span class="user" data-id="4-1"></span>//user object
<span class="user" data-id="4-2"></span>//user object
```

**UPDATE**

I might need more of your guys help...
The logic I want to code is the following:
1) when page loads(will use php to load elements from database), move all user elements to the matched desk(thank you all for the advice).
2) there may be situations where more than one user is assigned to a desk. In that situation, a css class of shared is to be added(shows 2 colors indicating more than one user is sitting there).

Question:

I went with Nathan's code. How do I adjust this code to account for two matches to the same data-id and add the css class "shared" along with the element info(info most likely will be the database id populated by php)? I adjusted two user elements to the same data ID as one of the desks.

Here is more info on my project(I have eliminated some redundant or unnecessary parts of the code):

```
<style>
#elementContainer {
    background: green;
    bottom: -180px; //theres animation for this that i have not included since its not relevent
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;

}
.shared {
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, pink 50%, red 50%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, pink 50%, red 50%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, pink 50%, red 50%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, pink 50%, red 50%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, pink 50%, red 50%);
}
.dragTest{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
}
td{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 1px;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}


.row{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
</style>

<div class='seatingChart'>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"><!-- Group 5 -->
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="desk" data-id="5-1"></td>
                        <td class="desk" data-id="5-2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="desk" data-id="5-3"></td>
                        <td class="desk" data-id="5-4"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="desk" data-id="5-5"></td>
                        <td class="desk" data-id="5-6"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="desk" data-id="5-7"></td>
                        <td class="desk" data-id="5-8"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div><!-- End of Group 5 -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<div id='elementContainer'>
    <div class="container">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'>
            <div class="user" data-id="5-8" data-name='Terry' info=""></div>
            <div class="user" data-id="5-2" data-name='Carlos' info=""></div>
            <div class="user" data-id="5-1" data-name='Mary' info=""></div>
            <div class="user shared" data-id="5-1" data-name='Tammy' info=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.desk').each(function() {
        var $desk = $(this),
            deskId = $desk.data('id'),
            $users = $('.dragTest[data-id="' + deskId + '"]');
            if($users.length) {
                $desk.append($users);
            }
    });
});//end of script
</script>
```

Comment: You need to provide some basic code, the problem statement is ok but what have you done so far?  Read the [ask] page to help you improve the question and you'll get good/quick answers from the community

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out. Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: @user247326 did you still want me to expand on this with the info from your update, or are you good now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because very little information has been given regarding the structure of your page and what needs to happen with each individual dom object, I'll limit my response to gathering like-id'd items.

Essentially you need to start with your desks, and for each desk gather the users which need to be linked to it. You can achieve this via jQuery's `each` method.

```
$('.desk').each(function() {
    var $desk = $(this),
        deskId = $desk.data('id'),
        $users = $('.user[data-id="' + deskId + '"]');

    // You now have a jQuery array of users with id's that match
    // this desk. Specific code goes here.
});
```

Obviously the code above is limited in its helpfulness, but without more information it is going to be hard to give more specific guidance.

Comment: Hey Nathan, I have added more information on what I want to accomplish, do you think you can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <span class="desk" data-id="4-1">//desk object</span>
<br>
<span class="desk" data-id="4-2">//desk object</span>
    <br>
<span class="desk" data-id="4-3">//desk object</span>
<br>
<span class="user" data-id="4-1">user object</span>
    <br>
<span class="user" data-id="4-2">user object</span>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Re-Arrange"/>


   <script>
    $('#btn').click(function()
                    {
    $(".desk").each(function(){
        var desk = $(this);
        $(".user").each(function()
        {
            var user = $(this);       
            if($(user).attr("data-id") == $(desk).attr("data-id"))
            {
               $(desk).append("<br/>");
                $(desk).append($(user));

            }            
        });    
    });
    });

 </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbc6cs1u/1/

Answer (score 0):

One solution possible :

```js
$('.desk').each(function(){
  var el = $(this);
  var id = el.attr('data-id');
  var user = $('.user[data-id="'+id+'"]');
  el.text(  'desk : ' + id );
  if(user.length) el.append(user.text('user'));
})
```

```css
.desk{
  border : solid brown 1px;
  border-radius : 6px;
  padding : 12px;
  margin : 3px;
  display : inline-block;
}

.user{
  border : solid green 1px;
  border-radius : 3px;
  padding : 3px;
  margin : 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desk" data-id="4-1"></div>
<div class="desk" data-id="4-2"></div>
<div class="desk" data-id="4-3"></div>

<span class="user" data-id="4-1"></span>
<span class="user" data-id="4-2"></span>
```

Comment: just tired, apparently I dont have enough "reputation" points